# whomsoever vs whosoever

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, case

> One hour in the week was set aside by him for the reception of **whomsoever** chose to visit him.
>
> One hour in the week was set aside by him for the reception of **whosoever** chose to visit him.

What is the correct fit among the two here?

For me, any confusion between **whomever** and **whoever** boils down to a choice between **him** and **he**. Going by the same logic, it is "he chose to visit him" and not "him chose to visit him". So I thought it should be "whosoever" instead of "whomsoever".

But according to my book "whomsoever" is correct.

Please clarify the difference.

Comment: Your book is wrong. You're right; _whosoever_ is the subject of _chose_, and that means it can't be _whomsoever_. In general, I would recommend that no one ever use the word _whomsoever_ at all; nor even the word _whom_. They're not useful and confuse even native speakers. _Who_ can work in any situation; _whom_ is never required.

Comment: "Whatsoever" seems natural, especially in a legal context.  "Whomsoever" does not.  Are there any examples where "whomsoever" is appropriate, and "whomever" is not?  I use "whom" sometimes; I use "whomever" rarely; I cannot recall the last time I used "whomsoever".  (No, I do not expect the original poster to provide such examples.)

Comment: @John, *whomsoever* follows *of* and so is governed by that.  *chose* is subordinate to the *whomsoever* and has no effect here.

Comment: So you're claiming that any single word following a preposition is guaranteed to be its object?  That rule produces  *_I'm puzzled by whom did it_. See what I mean about it confusing even native speakers?

Answer (score 2):

You are completely correct, the book is wrong.

Whomsoever is defined as object case of whosoever:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whomsoever?s=t

> whosoever chose to visit him.

"Whosoever" is the subject of the verb "chose". "Whomsoever" is an object form, so it cannot take "whosoever"'s place.

My preferred form of the sentence is:

> One hour in the week was set aside by him for the reception of whoever chose to visit him.

Answer (score 0):

Your book is truly wrong; the correct answer is 'whosoever'.

I thought to expand on the other answer by answering the question: Why? ELU SE already features many posts which explain this difference, such as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/166875/50720), and so which obviates the need to explain it myself, but I will summarise the key notion:

> [[Source:]](https://redd.it/11n8i6) The case of 'whoever/whomever' is determined by its usage in the subordinate clause, not the case of the subordinate clause's usage in the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

"**whosoever**" is nominative case; it's like "**he**".
"**whomsoever**" is accusative case; like "**him**".

We can isolate the noun phrase:

> One hour in the week was set aside by him for **the reception of whomsoever chose to visit him**.

Now we can replace the object of that noun phrase:

> the reception of (**he**/**him**)

It should be clear that **him** is correct in this simplified version, so **whomsoever** is correct in the full version.